# Android SDK Crash on StartUp and Crashes over and over again

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Moved to the Google Firebase SDK get the following exception again and again. Any suggestion or workarounds. Android SDK for me seems to be completely unstable.

```
07-18 22:12:14.696 12813-12813/com.ontymevalet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.ontymevalet, PID: 12813
                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagf$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                              Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalo.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalo.zzcp(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiz.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiz.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzais.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzais.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahk.zzri(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaht.zzcrg(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaht.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaht$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: have you tried a different version of the google firebase sdk? what does your build.gradle file look like

Comment: Nope I am using the latest one                                                        'compile com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1
    compile com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1
    compile com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1
    compile com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'

Comment: so what happens when you rebuild with 9.0.0 instead? Please edit your question to show the full build.gradle file. Make sure that google play services is in the build.gradle file as well as updated from the SDK Manager and that `google-services.json` exists in your project

Comment: @quidproquo unfortunately I had to roll back. I couldn't continue with such instability. I followed each and every step mentioned in the migration guide for Firebase [Migration](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android). I didn't try building with any other version. My assumption was that the latest version would be the best to use.